# Python unittest: test a test

Tags: python, unit-testing, floating-point

I'm writing some code that works with both very large and very small floating point numbers (for example, 1e-150 could be a valid answer). To unit test this I'd like to compare floats to a number of significant figures instead of decimal places, so I have the following.

```
import unittest as ut
from numpy.testing import assert_approx_equal

class newTestCase(ut.TestCase):
"""Extends the basic unittest TestCase."""

def assertSFAlmostEqual(self, a, b, places=7):
    """Uses numpy to test if two floats are the same but to a defined
    number of significant figures rather than decimal places.

    Args:
        a: float to be compared
        b: float to be compared
        places: number of significant figures to match. unittest default
        for assertAlmostEqual is 7, so 7 is the default here
    """
    if isinstance(a, float) != True or isinstance(b, float) != True:
        raise TypeError

    raised = False
    try:
        assert_approx_equal(a, b, significant=places)
    except:
        raised = True
    self.assertFalse(raised, "FLoats %g and %g are not equal to %i "
                     "significant figures" % (a, b, places))
```

Which seems to work fine, but I'm planning to use this in a lot of places, so I'd like to be certain that it really works correctly. My question is how can I do this most sensibly? Is there an proper mechanism to unit test a unit test?

I found what may be an answer here,

[How to unittest unittest TestCases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308435/how-to-unittest-unittest-testcases)

but I don't understand how this works.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subclass of `unittest.TestCase` is like *any* other class, hence you can write a `unittest.TestCase` that checks whether its methods work as they should.

In particular you should build sets of pairs of numbers that should pass and fail the test, and then call the `assertSFAlmostEqual` method with these inputs and see whether the test pass or fail.

The answer you linked does this, even though it's probably a more complicated solution than what's required. For example, I'd simply have written something like:

```
import unittest


class MyBaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertSpec(self, thing):
        assert thing == 123


class TestMyTest(MyBaseTestCase):
    def test_failures(self):
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, self.assertSpec, 121)

    def test_successes(self):
        self.assertSpec(123)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

You simply subclass the test-case and al the tests simply call the `assert*` method you wrote with specific arguments that you know should pass/not pass the test.

---

Some notes on your current implementation of the `assert*` method:

```
if isinstance(a, float) != True or isinstance(b, float) != True:
```

Avoid comparing with `True` or `False`. In your case you can simply write:

```
if not isinstance(a, float) or not isinstance(b, float):
# or:
if not (isinstance(a, float) and isinstance(b, float))
```

Which is also clearer to read.

```
raised = False
try:
    assert_approx_equal(a, b, significant=places)
except:
    raised = True
```

**Never** catch exceptions using a plain `except:`. In this case you really want to catch only the `AssertionError` raised by `assert_approx_equal`, hence you should use:

```
raised = False
try:
    assert_approx_equal(a, b, significant=places)
except AssertionError:
    raised = True
```

Secondly, you can avoid using the `raised` flag. The `try-except` statement allows an `else` clause that is executed only when no exception was raised:

```
try:
    assert_approx_equal(a, b, significant=places)
except AssertionError:
    # here put the code to be executed when the assertion fails.
else:
    # here put the code to be executed when *no* exception was raised.
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this has worked nicely. And thank you also for the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

One way is TDD (Test Driven Development):

1. Write a failing test.
2. Make the code pass the test.
3. Refactor.
4. Goto 1.

The crux here is to write a failing test first.